How to use /; The way to solve this problem?

How to find the cumulative value through the abstract function analytic expression?
Previous post was the same question but not using /; The way to solve the problem. So I re-opened a post looking to use /; The way to solve this problem
My question is: how do I use the point that the function g[x] is symmetric about the line x==4? My personal attempt is this: but there are several values of g[x] that have not been found
Clear["`*"]
g[4] = 8
g[x_ /; x >= 4] = g[8 - x]
f[x_ /; 8 >= x >= 4] = 4 - g[4 - x]
f[x_ /; x > 8] = g[-x + 16] - 8
f[x_ /; 0 < x < 4] = 4 - g[4 + x]
f[x_ /; x <= 0] = g[x + 8] - 8
\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(16\)]\(f[2  m]\)\)

get the result:
-72 + g[-16] + g[-14] + g[-12] + g[-10] + g[-8] + g[-6] + g[2]


"Previous post was the same question but not using /; " Are you serious? And, you're still mimicking blindly. (-1)

Possible duplicate of How to find the cumulative value through the abstract function analytic expression?


This question is beyond mma's capabilities, and should be deduced beforehand using math.

These equations
{
    f[x] + g[4 - x] == 4, 
    g[4] == 8,
    g[x] - f[x - 8] == 8,
    g[4 + x] == g[4 - x],
}

is equivalent mathematically to
{
    g[4] == 8,
    g[x] == g[8 - x],
    g[x] == -g[12 - x] + 12,
    f[x] == g[x + 8] - 8
}

then equivalent to
(*The symbol <- below means the right implies the left.*)
{
    g[4] == 8,
    g[x] == g[x - 8] <- x != x - 8, (*Reals->{0,8}*)
    g[x] == -g[x + 4] + 12 <- x != x + 4, (*{0,8}->{4,8}*)
    g[x] == -g[12 - x] + 12 <- x != 12 - x, (*{4,8}->{4,6}*)
    g[x] == -g[12 - x] + 12 <- x == 12 - x, (*6->6*)
    f[x] == g[x + 8] - 8
}

then, we can use mma to define this two function:
g[4] := 8;
g[x_ /; ! 0 <= x < 8] := g[Mod[x - 8, 8]];
g[x_ /; ! 4 <= x < 8] := -g[x + 4] + 12;
g[x_ /; ! 4 <= x <= 6] := -g[12 - x] + 12;
g[6] := 6;
f[x_] := g[x + 8] - 8;
Sum[f[2 m], {m, 1, 16}]

the result is $-32$.

$g(4)=8$ is actually a redundant condition.

$g(x), 4\leqslant x\leqslant 6$ is undefined and function value on other interval depends on it.

I'm glad you can help me answer this question, thank you very much!

The code I have the first unclear place: why the left side of the interval should be added! This symbol, why is that?I tried it and I couldn't get it right without this

@csn899, it's Not.

Second problem: Since these functions are related to each other in the interval. Why did I change the maximum value of m to 18? In fact g[x] is a function of period 8, g[x_ /;! 0 <= x < 8] := g[Mod[X-8, 8]] This sentence is reflected, why does mathematica not have a certain universality for this kind of problem?

@csn899 ! is just for concision, you can expand it: $x<0\vee x\geqslant 8$, $0\leqslant x<4$, $6<x<8$

Meanwhile, it can emphasize the narrowed interval.

I can't understand your second problemt, can you explain it more clearly?

When I change the maximum value of m for the sum to 18, i.eSum[f[2  m], {m, 1, 18}]The result is:-28 - g[6],Why can't the value of g[6] be calculated, isn't the interval already containing 6?

No, I mentioned before, because $g(6)$ is not defined by these equations.

  is undefined and function value on other interval depends on it.```What relation do we use to define this interval?

@csn899 Definition is directed, while equation is undirected, so we need to implicitly indicate the direction, here, the order of definition of g indicates this direction.

@csn899 No equation is applicable, so it is left undefined.

@csn899 The criterion is: whether the mapped interval $g(I)$is subset of $I$.

The values for g[2], g[4], g[6], g[8], etc. can actually be computed by hand. It is known that g[4] = 8, and there is a relation g[x] = -g[12 - x] + 12, which is valid for the entire real number range. When x=4, we get g[4] = -g[8] + 12, from which we can derive g[8] = 4; since the period of g[x] is 8, then g[0] = g[8] = g[16] = g[24] = ... = 4. When x=6, we obtain g[6] = 6. Also, g[x] = g[8-x], so when x=2, we have g[2] = g[6] = 6. However, in the Mathematica language, each relation must include its domain of validity; otherwise, it leads to an infinite loop.

So, can software not think like a human brain? So you can only enter g[2] = 6 manually;
g[4] = 8;
g[6] = 6;
g[8] = 4; What are these values?

Clear["`*"] g[2] = 6; g[4] = 8; g[6] = 6; g[8] = 4; g[x_ /; ! 0 <= x < 8] := g[Mod[x - 8, 8]]; g[x_ /; ! 4 <= x < 8] := -g[x + 4] + 12; g[x_ /; ! 4 <= x <= 6] := -g[12 - x] + 12; f[x_] := g[x + 8] - 8; Sum[f[2  m], {m, 1, 99}]After adding those values manually, you can calculate any other values. Is this the only way?

@csn899 Oh, I only concern the transition, missing the case of "self-defined" , which can't be solved by mma, but solved otherwise by hand.
So, add one check for this case.

I will revise my answer.

Now the real undefined interval is $4\leqslant x < 6$.(I don't think the condition $g(4)=8$ should be mentioned).

Just add one, it's worth considering carefully
