How to find the value of $f(2023) + f(2024)$?
Given that the function $f(x)$ has a domain of $\mathbb{R}$ and for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, the equation $f(x - y) \cdot f(x + y) = (f(x) - f(y)) \cdot (f(x) + f(y))$ always holds true. Moreover, it is given that $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 0$. We are asked to find the value of $f(2023) + f(2024)$.
I tried this method and did not succeed in finding it.
RecurrenceTable[{f[x - y] f[x + y] == (f[x] - f[y]) (f[x] + f[y]), 
  f[1] == 2, f[2] == 0}, f, {x, 2024}, {y, 2024}]


(-1) Again, you're pretending you've made effort with obviously wrong code, and this is at least 8th time you ask about this type of problem: 1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299614/1871 2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299613/1871 3. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299612/1871 4. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299605/1871 5. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299596/1871 6. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/302375/1871 7. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/302437/1871

I’m voting to close this question because OP has posted similar questions whose answers could be used ti answer question.

I think your questions belong to math.stackexchange. Even though you got some answers here, functional equations of this kind do not have a general solution method. Therefore, there is no single Mathematica function that you can simply use.

Formula of first-order logic with two bound variables, each transition with $\aleph_0$ relations, you can't choose one as definition randomly, computing of $f(x)$ is impossible. The only way of computing is deducing from initial values.

This deduction involves complex and brute logical deduction, which can be represented by program, but needs much time invested.
But the initial values given are too special and allow us to grasp the laws and conclude solution for $f(x), x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I note and agree with comments. IMHO these questions require some thought rather than blindly using in-built functions and can be approached in a number of ways. I may have made a mistake. If so I'll delete.
With a small amount of pen and paper effort it can be shown that the following satisfies the relations (similar to other questions by OP):
f[n_?OddQ] := (-1)^Floor[n/2]  2
f[n_?EvenQ] := 0

Therefore,
f[2023] + f[2024]

is (-2).
You can do some reality checking, e.g.
tup = Tuples[Range[5], 2];
{Row[{HoldForm[f[#1 + #2] f[#1 - #2]], " = " , 
      f[#1 + #2] f[#1 - #2]}], 
    Row[{HoldForm[f[#1]^2 - f[#2]^2], " = ", f[#1]^2 - f[#2]^2}]} & @@@
   tup // Grid[#,Frame->All]&


